# Origin of the name "Lichfett"?

Tags: etymology, person-names

Does someone know where the family name *Lichfett* comes from? I met this name in Brazil. Is it perhaps only a modified version of *Lichtfett*?

Comment: This is a wild guess (and probably wrong) but perhaps it has to do with embalming? "Lich" + "fett"?

Comment: Probably related to English "lich", "like" and German "Leiche" in the old sense of "body". German has the name as "Lickfett" as well.

Comment: @CTKlein That could be a good idea - thinking about the word *Leiche*.

Comment: @Emanuel Thanks! I did not know that in English "lich" exists.

Comment: Full credit goes to Warcraft 3... the Lich-king :D

Comment: Google for Namensforschung, Onomastik, Familiennamen.

Comment: Number of results on Google: "Lichfett": ~3030; "Lickfett": ~31100; "Lichtfett": ~120 (double quotes are necessary)

Comment: The name "Lickfett" appears to be common only in the extreme north of Germany, particularly Hamburg and the North Sea coast. Based on this, I would guess it's either Danish or Frisian in origin.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it should be asked on genealogy.stackexchange. It asks for the origin of a name.

Comment: @Jan: I opened [a Meta discussion on the on-topicness of such questions](http://meta.german.stackexchange.com/q/890/2594).

Answer (score 5):

*I’m going to answer this in German first:*

Abhängig von den in verschiedenen Regionen Deutschlands gebräuchlichen 
Mundarten (Dialekten) haben sich verschiedene Schreibweisen für Namen ergeben.  Zum Beispiel gibt es den häufigen Name „Schultze“ auch als „Schulze“.

Viele Nachnamen in Deutschland wurden im frühen Mittelalter in der Feudalgesellschaft aus den damaligen Berufen abgeleitet:
„Meier“, „Müller“, „Bauer“ und „Schmied“ bzw. „Schmidt“ sind am häufigsten.

„Lichtfett“ ist ein sehr altes Synonym für „Lampenöl“, was insbesondere im frühen Bergbau unentbehrlich war, um Licht in die dunklen Stollen zu bringen.

Ich **vermute** deshalb, dass dieser Name seinen Ursprung auch in einem Beruf 
hat.  Aber wie Jan oben in einem Kommentar schon schrieb, hat diese Frage nur am Rande mit der deutschen Sprache und mehr mit Genealogie zu tun.

*In English:*

Depending on the German dialects spoken in different regions of Germany, the
way names are spelled is different.  For example the name *Schultze* is also very often seen written as *Schulze*.

In the early Middle Age, many surnames in Germany were deviated from the professions of the time: *Meier*, *Müller* and *Schmidt* are the most common.

*Lichtfett* is an **old-fashioned** word for the oil needed to fuel lamps used in mining, which were very important at the time.

I therefore **assume** that the name *Lichfett* also originates from a profession.  As Jan suggested above, this question should have been asked in a forum about [genealogy](http://genealogy.stackexchange.com).

Comment: German is fine.